# How I can animate this slideshow(by changing its src)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Okay okay, so before marking this post as repeated. Let me explain to you:

I made a slideshow in `javascript(Vue)` and it works by changing its `src` in an object every time I press a button(next)

It works and all but the problem is that it doesn't get animated no matter what I do, I made a transition on them, set timeout function on it...etc and nothing even the smallest worked.

I could have made another idea which works by the position absolute but I don't want to do that because it will take a loot of time and it will be extremely buggy as position absolute ruins it. So any help on this please?

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div id="slideshow">
      <figure id="pics">
        <img id="slidepic" v-bind:src="pictures[count].src">
        <figcaption>{{pictures[count].alt}}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <p>{{count+1}}/{{pictures.length}}</p>
    <div id="controls">
      <div @click="move(-1)">Previous</div>
      <div @click="move(1)">Next</div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Javascript:

```
  methods: {
    move: function(num) {
      let slideimg = document.querySelector("#slidepic");
      slideimg.classList.add("fadeOut");
      this.count += num;
      if (this.count < 0) {
        this.count = this.pictures.length - 1;
      } else if (this.count >= this.pictures.length) {
        this.count = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        slideimg.src = this.pictures[1].src;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

CSS:

```
#pics {
  opacity: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#pics.fadeOut {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I didn't include the object(that is in data object, something in `Vue`) because it would be useless in this situation.

Comment: Help? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention you want to build a slideshow on Vue JS, and because jQuery on top of Vue is not recommended, I suggest that you try [Vueper Slides](https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/#examples), available on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vueperslides). Unless it is for a learning purpose.

Answer (score 2):

First off all it's `transition: <property-name> 0.5s linear;` and not `transition: 0.5s;`. See the [transition documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

There is no animation for changing the src of an image (see [list of animatable css properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)).

To do something like this, you can stack all your images into one element and then use css animations and the transform property to create a carousel

```js
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');

next.onclick = function() {
  var lastChild = slideshow.children[slideshow.children.length - 1];
  var firstChild = slideshow.children[0];
  var activeEle = document.querySelector('.item.active');
  var nextEle = document.querySelector('.item.next');
  var prevEle = document.querySelector('.item.prev');

  activeEle.classList.remove('active');
  activeEle.classList.add('prev');
  nextEle.classList.add('active');
  nextEle.classList.remove('next');
  prevEle.classList.remove('prev');
  
  if (nextEle.nextElementSibling) {
    nextEle.nextElementSibling.classList.add('next');
  } else {
    firstChild.classList.add('next');
  }
};

prev.onclick = function() {
  var lastChild = slideshow.children[slideshow.children.length - 1];
  var activeEle = document.querySelector('.item.active');
  var nextEle = document.querySelector('.item.next');
  var prevEle = document.querySelector('.item.prev');

  // Move the .active class to the previous element
  activeEle.classList.remove('active');
  activeEle.classList.add('next');
  prevEle.classList.add('active');
  prevEle.classList.remove('prev');
  nextEle.classList.remove('next');

  if (prevEle.nextElementSibling) {
    prevEle.nextElementSibling.classList.add('prev');
  } else {
    lastChild.classList.add('prev');
  }
};
```

```css
#slideshow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  /*display: none;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  transition: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.next {
  transform: translateX(200%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.prev {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="item active">1</div>
  <div class="item next">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item prev">7</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="prev">Prev</button><button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: I know that I can use that way where I stack all elements together and I tell you that I already did that before, but the problem is that it's extremely buggy and hard to position stuff by using that way.

Comment: Thank you for the help though you too!

Comment: @Boypro Yea, I know, this is why I use slickjs. But that would be bad for you since you are using vuejs and if I remember correctly it uses a virtual DOM

Comment: Yeah, I will just use a package so, position: absolute/height: 0 is extremely buggy and I don't think I take that anymore. For slickjs, I believe it would work within Vue.

Comment: @Boypro then please, use it, it gets kinda tricky btw when you are trying to customize it. Also remember that there's jQuery required and that usually doesn't play well with vDOM libraries

Answer (score 1):

I have created two solutions.

First of all. You've a typo.

```
#pics {
  opacity: 0.5s; // <--- remove "s"
  transition: 0.5s; // <--- and forgot the property-name (all, opacity ...)
}
#pics.fadeOut {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I commented all lines I've changed.

**Solution**

```
<template>
    <main>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <!--
                I recommend to you ref inestad of querySelector.
                https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

                I've used the v-bind shorthand.
            -->
            <figure id="pics1" ref="pics1">
                <img id="slidepic" :src="pictures[count].src">
                <figcaption>{{pictures[count].alt}}</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <!--
                VueJS build-in transition element.
                You have to add a key attribute to detect that the content has changed.
                I recommend to use this instead of your solution.
                It's easier to implement, no class add/remove struggle, its a part of vue, you can add hooks etc.
                https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html
            -->
            <transition tag="figure" name="fade" ref="pics2">
                <figure id="pics2" :key="`figure-${count}`">
                    <img :src="pictures[count].src">
                    <figcaption>{{pictures[count].alt}}</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </transition>
        </div>

        <p>{{count+1}}/{{pictures.length}}</p>
        <div id="controls">
            <div @click="move(-1)">Previous</div>
            <div @click="move(1)">Next</div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'teams',
    data() {
        return {
        count: 0,
        pictures: [
            {
                src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
                alt: 'test'
            },
            {
                src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/400',
                alt: 'test2'
            }
        ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        // instead of move: function(num) {} you can also write move() {}
        move(num) {
            this.count += num;
            if (this.count < 0) {
                this.count = this.pictures.length - 1;
            } else if (this.count >= this.pictures.length) {
                this.count = 0;
            }
        }
    },
    // Watch "count" changes and add or remove classes
    // you can also add this to your "move" method
    watch: {
        count() {
            // access the reference
            const element = this.$refs.pics1;

            element.classList.add('fadeOut');
            element.classList.remove('fadeIn');

            setTimeout(() => {
                element.classList.remove('fadeOut');
                element.classList.add('fadeIn');
            }, 500); // same duration as css transition
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
#pics1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
#pics1.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
#pics1.fadeOut {
    opacity: 0;
}


// All classes for <transition> 
// There are all automatically used by vue
.fade-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-leave {
    display: none;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but this is not exactly what I wanted, it gives a transition to the picture AFTER it appears. Welp, I guess you can't transition a src like the other guy said. Thank you again, it was useful though.